# Accessing a UITextField from an array in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have 4 UITextFields that I'm dynamically creating, in the viewDidLoad, which works good.  I want to reference those objects when the UISlider value changes.  Right now I'm storing those objects in a NSMutableArray and accessing them like so from the sliderChanged method:

```
    NSInteger labelIndex = [newText intValue];
labelIndex--;

NSUInteger firstValue = (int)0;

NSMutableArray *holeArray = [pointsArray objectAtIndex:labelIndex];
UITextField *textField = [textFieldArray objectAtIndex:firstValue];
NSString *newLabel1Text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[holeArray objectAtIndex:firstValue] stringValue]];

[textField setText: newLabel1Text];

[newLabel1Text release];
```

Everything is working good, but the program crashes on the setText: method.  The last message I get from the program is: [UILabel drawTextInRect:]  and then I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS failure.

I want to be able to acces that dynamically created UITextField, but I must be going about it the wrong way.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are actually getting a textfield from that array?  Also double check that your string for your textField is actually a string.

Comment: @MishieMoo he isn't even using the text fields that he said he created, he's creating new ones and not defining where it is

Comment: I checked the array and it is holding 4 UITextField objects.  newLabel1Text is: @"0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, yea, you create a text field, but you aren't displaying the field itself, just creating it.

If you want to do what I think you want to do, I would just do if statements.

ex.

```
if (firstValue == 1)
{
 fieldone.text = @"whatever";
}
else if (firstValue == 2)
{
fieldtwo.text = @"whatever";
}
```

Comment: The text fields have been added to the view.  I'm trying to access them dynamcially, and set their text properties.  I saw a posting about accessing objects by their tag property.  Would that be a better way to go?

Comment: the fields may have been added, but your code is creating a NEW textfield (hence the `UITextField *`) and you probably could use tags, but I wouldn't

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I changed it to use tags and it's working wonderfully!